# get current date with country after setLocale in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, date, php-carbon

I want to show current date based on several countries. I used this code

```
$mytime = Carbon\Carbon::now();
echo $mytime->toDateTimeString();
```

I use the setLocale() method in a middleware by country. but $mytime so returned current server date. What is the true solution?

Comment: try that `Carbon::now()->locale('xx_XX');`

Comment: Locale has to do with the formatting. If you want to also get the local time set the timezone as well

Comment: i used this but so returned current server time.

Answer (score 0):

**Carbon** uses the default [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) PHP object, like :

```
Carbon::now('Europe/London');
```

So if you want you use timezone with **Carbon**. Then it should be matched on **PHP DateTime TimeZone format**
[List of Supported TimeZone on PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Answer (score 0):

I first got the default server date. Then I was able to get the date and time of Iran by the **date_default_timezone_set method ("Asia / Tehran")**. And again with this function we can get the history of any country we want

```
 date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Tehran");
    $persianDate = new \DateTime(Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString());
    $persianDate = $persianDate->format('Y-m-d H:i');

    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Istanbul");
    $TurkishDate = new \DateTime(Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString());
    $TurkishDate = $TurkishDate->format('F d Y');

    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Seoul");
    $koreanDate = new \DateTime(Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString());
    $koreanDate = $koreanDate->format('F d Y');

    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
    $londonDate = new \DateTime(Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString());
    $londonDate = $londonDate->format('F d Y');
```

If you use all pages of the site

```
    View::share("persianDate",$persianDate);
    View::share("turkishDate",$TurkishDate);
    View::share("koreanDate",$koreanDate);
    View::share("londonDate",$londonDate);
```